# Gamma Likelihood in R

Tags: r, math

I want to plot the posterior distribution for data sampled from `gamma(2,3)` with a prior distribution of `gamma(3,3)`. I am assuming `alpha=2` is known. But a graph of my posterior for different values of the rate parameter centers around `4`. It should be `3`. I even tried with a uniform prior to make things simpler. Can you please spot what's wrong? Thank you.

```r
set.seed(101)
dat <- rgamma(100,shape=2,rate=3)
alpha <- 3
n <- 100
post <- function(beta_1) {
   posterior<- (((beta_1^alpha)^n)/gamma(alpha)^n)*
            prod(dat^(alpha-1))*exp(-beta_1*sum(dat))  
   return(posterior)
}
vlogl <- Vectorize(post)
curve(vlogl2,from=2,to=6)
```

Comment: Hello. Hmm....why should I change "sum(dat)" to "dat"? The product of e^x1*e^x2....is e^(x1+x2+....).

Answer (score 1):

A tricky question and possibly more related to statistics than to programming =). I initially made the same reasoning mistake as you, but subsequently realised to be more careful with the posterior and the roles of *alpha* and *beta_1*.

- The prior is uniform (or flat) so the posterior distribution is **proportional (not equal)** to the likelihood.
- The quantity you have assigned to the posterior is indeed the likelihood. Plugging in *alpha=3*, this evaluates to

```
 (prod(dat^2)/(gamma(alpha)^n)) * beta_1^(3*n)*exp(-beta_1*sum(dat)).
```

- This is the crucial step. The last two terms in the product depend on `beta_1` only, so these two parts determine the shape of the posterior. The posterior distribution is thus gamma distributed with shape parameter *3*n+1* and rate parameter *sum(dat)*. As the mode of the gamma distribution is the ratio of these two and *sum(dat)* is about 66 for this seed, we get a mode of 301/66 (about 4.55). This coincides perfectly with the ``posterior plot'' (again you plotted the likelihood which is not properly scaled, i.e. not properly integrating to 1) produced by your code (attached below).

[image]

I hope LifeisBetter now =).

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you so much! Just wanted to add a little note that the mean of the gamma distribution is alpha/beta, not the mode (I had to Google the mode of a gamma dist. haha).

Answer (score 0):

> But a graph of my posterior for different values of the rate parameter
> centers around `4`. It should be `3`.

The mean of your data is 0.659 (~2/3). Given a gamma distribution with a shape parameter `alpha = 3`, we are trying to find likely values of the rate parameter, `beta`, that gave rise to the observed data (subject to our prior information). The mean of a gamma distribution is the shape parameter divided by the rate parameter. 100 observations should be enough to mostly overcome the somewhat informative prior (which had a mean of 1), so we should expect `beta` to take values somewhere in the region `alpha/mean(dat)`, not 3.

```
alpha/mean(dat)
#> [1] 4.54915
```

I'm not going to show the derivation of the posterior distribution for `beta` without TeX, but it is a gamma distribution that includes the rate parameter from the prior distribution of `beta` (`betaPrior = 3`):

```
set.seed(101)
n <- 100
dat <- rgamma(n, 2, 3)
alpha <- 3
betaPrior <- 3

post <- function(x) dgamma(x, alpha*(n + 1), sum(dat) + betaPrior)
curve(post, 2, 6)
```

[image]

Notice that the mean of `beta` is at ~4.39 rather than ~4.55 because of the informative prior that had a mean of 1.